# C++ same variable act as int and float

Tags: c++

I have on situation, where i need to keep the value float as well as int. so tried like below. but no help. can any one help on this?

```
union Val {
        int a;
        float b;
    };

    Val p;
    p.b = 45.56;

    int k = p.a; // i want k should be 45;
```

Comment: unions dont work like this. Your union holds either an `int` or a `float` but not both. What do you actually want to do? Seems like simple rounding would do the job

Comment: yes but i dont want each time it to be converted from float to int. any other idea

Comment: if you really want to save computation at the expense of memory then simply use a `struct Val { int a; float b; }` ... or make `a` private and provide a lazy access function, that does the rounding only the first time the value is accessed.

Comment: you don't need anything special to make int k = p.b to be 45.  That will happen automatically.  When you assign a floating point value to an integer, the fractional part is dropped.

Comment: you mean assign value to both a and b on initialization and use occordingly

Comment: @xaxxon right, I wasnt sure if he really just wants simple rounding or perhaps a more complicated conversion. For simple rounding, a `struct {int a;float b}` is of course compete overkill

Comment: please clarify if the `int` should be simply the rounded `float` or if there is some heavy computation involved to get the `int` from the `float`

Comment: @xaxxon i am afraid if i use that in loop which will go for 50000 iteration will it affect performance, because i believe, for int k = p.b, it is internally converting float to in each time.

Comment: dont be afraid unless you really observe some performance problem. When in doubt, you should always profile your code before(!) doing any optimizations. To make the implicit conversion have any effect on the runtime of your code it has to be code that does little else than this conversion.

Comment: @EZEROFIVEEMD you have no idea what kind of code the compiler will generate.   If you're worried about performance, then profile an optimized build.   Also, 50,000 iterations is trivial even in the worst case.

Comment: @EZEROFIVEEMD [I've suggested a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36718608/2642059) but I'm unclear what you want to happen when you assign an `int` to your object. Are you expecting the fractional portion of the `float` to be preserved? That's what I assume in my answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee not exactly, but your code helped me, thank you so much

Comment: @EZEROFIVEEMD If you want to clarify, I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee the answer you have posted gave me more idea. the operator overloading  concept is what i wanted, now i can do any operation on that value just on assignment(no need of internal or external conversion). thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that [you say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717725/c-same-variable-act-as-int-and-float#comment61020834_36717725):

> i dont want each time it to be converted from float to int [sic]

To do that you could use [user-defined conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) to accomplish this.

So your struct would look like this:

```
class Val {
    int a;
    float b;
public:
    Val& operator= (const int _a) {a = _a; b = _a + fmod(b, 1.0F); return *this;}
    Val& operator= (const float _b) {b = _b; a = trunc(_b); return *this;}
    operator int() {return a;}
    operator float() {return b;}
};
```

Please note that what you really want to use is simply a `float` with [`static_cast<int>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#static_cast) For a`static_cast`:

> No checks are performed during runtime to guarantee that the object being converted is in fact a full object of the destination type. Therefore, it is up to the programmer to ensure that the conversion is safe. On the other side, it does not incur the overhead of the type-safety checks of `dynamic_cast`.

I've provided an example of using `Val` here: http://ideone.com/XUesib but you could accomplish the exact same thing given `float foo` like this:

```
foo = 1.3F;
cout << static_cast<int>(foo) << endl << foo << endl;
foo = 13 + fmod(foo, 1.0F);
cout << static_cast<int>(foo) << endl << foo << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have on situation, where i need to keep the value float as well as int. so tried like below

You can't do it with a union. A union can only hold a single value inside at any time. You need two separate variables. You can keep them in side a struct if you like:

```
struct Val {
    int a;
    float b;
};
```

Now you can have both an int and a float.

```
 Val p;
 p.b = 45.56;
 p.a = p.b;

 int k = p.a; // no conversion
```

That said, since you apparently only use `a` to store a converted value of `b`, you should measure whether the conversions even affect performance.

Comment: just if you declare the variable k

Answer (score 0):

You can use structure with constructor, and initialize your variables in it as you wish.

```
struct Val {
    int a;
    float b;
    Val(float value) {
        a = b = value;
    }
};
```

So you can use it in loop and don't worry about conversations each time, just create your `Val` variable outside loop and use it.