# Assignment Operator Return

Tags: c++, operators, return-value, implicit, assign

I was working on an example for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718608/2642059) but I forgot to type `return *this;` to conclude my assignment operator, so `Val`'s assignment operator looks like this:

```
Val& operator= (const int _a) {a = _a; b = _a + fmod(b, 1.0F);}
```

It seems like it shouldn't, but [gcc compiles and runs this code](http://ideone.com/BhAmhW). How is this possible? Is this like the `main` function where there's an implied `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no implied return, but in default mode g++ does not report missing `return` as an error. The reason for this is that missing `return` makes a program ill-formed, and Standard does not require any reporting for ill-formed programs.

You need to make sure you always have following arguments to your g++: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`. This will make sure gcc will report errors like that and much more.

Comment: Missing return does _not_ make a program ill-formed. Reaching the end of that function without a return...does. Subtle difference but your function may throw an exception (for example) and that code be perfectly valid.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, if there is a nitpicking, this is the one. I'd edit, but since the question is a dupe anyways, I see no reason to :)